# How to use the Socket module *and* set ipv6_v6only?

Tags: sockets, elixir

I create an UDP socket with the [`Socket`](https://hexdocs.pm/socket/Socket.UDP.html#open/2) module and `version: 6`. I want it to listen only to IPv6 (by default, `version: 6` listens on both v4 and v6). Erlang's [inet module](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html) has a `ipv6_v6only` option but I don't know how to use it when using Elixir's `Socket` module. Calling [`:inet.setopts/2`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html#setopts-2) after the call to `Socket.UDP.open/2` always produce a `{:error, :einval}`. Any code example?

(I know I can do it by tuning the `net.ipv6.bindv6only` sysctl on Linux but I would prefer a solution that does not require to be root.)

Comment: The aforementioned library does not have a function `Socket.open`. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm very surprised by your comment. Not only there is a Socket.open but the first link in my question goes directly to it.

Comment: There is `Socket.UDP.open/2`, but there is no `Socket.open`. Anyway, I was able to get to the source finally.

Answer (score 0):

[`Socket.UDP.open/2`](https://github.com/meh/elixir-socket/blob/master/lib/socket/udp.ex#L77-L82) is effectively routed to [`:gen_udp.open/2`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_udp.html#open-2) which accepts a keyword of type [`open_option()`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_udp.html#type-open_option) as a second argument, which is in turn an extended type [`option()`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_udp.html#type-option).

Somewhat alongside the following would do

```elixir
Socket.UDP.socket(port, version: 6)
```

This could have been easily seen from the [`arguments/1`](https://github.com/meh/elixir-socket/blob/master/lib/socket/udp.ex#L169-L170) implementation I’ve linked above.

Comment: It does not work for me: ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in anonymous fn/1 in Socket.arguments/1    
    
    The following arguments were given to anonymous fn/1 in Socket.arguments/1:
    
        # 1
        {:ipv6_v6only, true}
    
    (socket) lib/socket.ex:170: anonymous fn/1 in Socket.arguments/1
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:2994: Enum.flat_map_list/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:2995: Enum.flat_map_list/2
    (socket) lib/socket/udp.ex:150: Socket.UDP.arguments/1
    (socket) lib/socket/udp.ex:81: Socket.UDP.open/2

Comment: Try `Socket.UDP.socket(port, [[ipv6_v6only: true]])` then.

Comment: Same error message.

Comment: OK, I grepped the linked source file for you and updated the answer to the tested solution.